# What does 食わず嫌いな奴は貪欲さで試合に負けるわ! Mean

Tags: meaning, manga

Please see picture for context:

If I understand correctly the girl on the right is making an observation that all of the food the people in the room are trying is new to her. Then the other girl in the middle says something along the lines of  either "Just try anything!" or "I challenge you to try anything". After that comes the line I don't really understand  much other than she's saying that "people who dislike food without even trying it (and this is where it gets weird) will lose the match with greed" which makes no sense to me. Does it makes sense to you?
Then

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

貪欲 is not necessarily a negative quality, unlike English greed (I may be wrong on the English connotation). It can mean something like *aggressive, voracious* or generally strong willpower.

Here the girl says that disliking food without eating (=lack of novelty-seeking quality) implies a lack of aggressiveness, which leads to defeat in competitions.

More literally で in 貪欲さで should mean 基準 or 理由, so the sentence mean *those who dislike foods without eating them will be defeated because of (lack of) aggressiveness in competitions.* (Even more literally: *in terms of aggressiveness/willpower/will to victory*.)

A relevant expression is Xは勝ちに貪欲だ which means X is always seeking a victory, never gives up, etc.

Comment: Alright! Makes much more sense now. In that case saying she is こじつけすぎ would mean she's "Too harsh when it comes to sports"?

Comment: @leosan こじつける means to associate things that are not really related. なんでもスポーツにこじつけすぎ means that the girl with blonde hair associates too many things to sports. So the girl with black hair thinks that disliking-food-without-eating-it has nothing to do with sports.

Comment: That makes more sense than what initially thought. The thing is when I looked it up on Jisho the definition for こじ付ける was to distort; to strain (interpretation); to force (meaning).

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it "to strain" might be the closest one to what you just said. Thanks for the help!